# Is there a name for the trailing "hiss" sound that people produce when pronoucing plurals?

Tags: post-production, adobe

Is there a name for the trailing "hiss" sound that people produce when pronouncing plurals?

It's not necessarily full-blown lisp. I'm referring to "trailing S sound" that produces hissing when certain people pronounce a plural word ending with an S. I have a narrator who does this throughout a promotional audio segment and I would like to remove or even just reduce it but it would help if it this occurrence had a name or a standard way to refer to it for the sake of Googling. I'm using Adobe Audition and ultimately I'm going to either trim the extreme instances of this hissing sound from the segment manually or try to use Audition to "capture a noise point" and then reduce it systematically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a sibilance, or sibilant articulation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant

You can avoid it in the recording process using a pop filter, but in post production there are a handful of de-essers available for taming those sounds. The process involves compressing just the frequency range that contains the sibilant consonants through multiband compression.

Comment: That's it! Thank you. Found out a great video on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-07flDfK4Q